# Wordpress: Non hierarchical taxonomy to be select only one in edit posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a taxonomy added with this code

```
function tmc_type_taxonomy()  {
    $type = array(
        'name'                       => 'Types',
        'singular_name'              => 'Type',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Types',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Types',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Type',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Type:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Type Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Type',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Type',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Type',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Types with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Types',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Types',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Types',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $type,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'rewrite'                    => array( 'slug' => 'type' ),
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,   
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'tmc_type', 'post', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tmc_type_taxonomy', 0 );
```

And it displays like the tags in wordpress.

I want to make it like a radio box. For this, I tried to do it hierarchical which displays the checkbox instead but I could not change it to radio through jquery with the code

```
function checktoradio(){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery("#id").each(function(){this.type="radio"});</script>';
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'checktoradio')
```

Because the sidebar in edit post page is loaded dynamically. So I cannot modify the checkbox as its not created yet in the footer hook.

How do I change it to select only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the scope of the question, you need to hook your JavaScript code to the "admin_enqueue_scripts" hook in this way:

```
// custom css and js
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cstm_css_and_js');
 
function cstm_css_and_js() {
   wp_enqueue_style('admin_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/admin.css');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/admin.js', array('jquery-core'), false, true );
}
```

And you should put your code inside the "admin.js" file.

this is the link to study more about this hook:
[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/#:~:text=admin_enqueue_scripts%20is%20the%20proper%20hook,informs%20the%20current%20admin%20page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/#:%7E:text=admin_enqueue_scripts%20is%20the%20proper%20hook,informs%20the%20current%20admin%20page).

But honestly, you need to focus on how you are going to apply your changes in the backend of your website.